# Laravel get user info by Jwt token

Tags: laravel, angular

I'm using laravel as my backend.
Once the user has logged into my app, all I have is just a token without any information regards the username or any other user details.

Once I retrive the JWT Token and store it in my frontend (angular2), how I can get the user details?

For the record, i'm using the following laravel library:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 4):

To get the user information

1. First get the token from JWTAuth like this:

   $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
2. Then get the user from the token as follows:

   $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);

Answer (score 0):

you can get user information like this way :

```
$user = JWTAuth::toUser(your_token_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested just

```
$user = JWTAuth::toUser();
```

Without any parameter and it works as well
I am using Laravel 7.3 with tymon/jwt-auth 1.0

Answer (score 0):

`JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504